# Troubles installing php with MySQL support

Tags: compiling, mysql, php

So I wasn't sure if this question would go best here or on Overflow or Server Fault, but decided to try here first. I'm installing LAMP on a VPS, and am running into issues configuring and building PHP. I've got MySQL installed, and it seems to be running fine. I'm trying to just go for a basic install of PHP with MySQL support as instructions are given here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

Here's the configure command I was running:

```
./configure –with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs –with-mysql
```

I was getting this error:

```
configure: error: Cannot find MySQL header files under yes.
Note that the MySQL client library is not bundled anymore!
```

I just had a basic, default MySQL install with yum install mysql-server mysql.

After some Googling, I installed mysql-devel to get rid of that error:

```
yum install mysql-devel
```

Then I started getting this error:

```
configure: error: Try adding –with-zlib-dir=<DIR>. Please check config.log for more   information.
```

Okay. So I changed my command to:

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql --with-zlib
```

Now I just get this:

```
configure: error: mysql configure failed. Please check config.log for more information.
```

Honestly kind of lost at this point. I'm looking at the config.log, but not exactly sure what I need to be looking for. Here's the sections I think may be relevant:

```
configure:60061: gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden-Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/mysql -L/usr/lib/mysql -L/usr/lib  conftest.c -lmysqlclient  -lz -lrt -lm -ldl -lnsl  -lxml2 -lz -lm -lxml2 -lz -lm 1>&5
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so when searching for -lmysqlclient
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.a when searching for -lmysqlclient
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure: failed program was:
#line 60050 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"
```

Any thoughts? Or should I be looking at something else in config.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend looking for binary packages for your distribution.

If you want to stick with building from source, I recommend that you start from a pristine source when you've installed new libraries. The `configure` program keeps a cache of what it's found, and sometimes won't realize that the cache is no longer up-to-date. If `configure` has finished running and produced a `Makefile`, then run `make distclean`. Otherwise, if PHP isn't doing anything too exotic, `rm config.cache config.status` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The manual you are following is bit complex. I suggest you following [Linode Guide on LAMP](http://library.linode.com/lamp-guides/ubuntu-11.10-oneiric) stack. Follow the steps one by one (it will hardly take 20 minutes) and you are done.

**NOTE:** If you are planning to run some open source apps then skip Suhosin (php5-suhosin) package for now. It gave problem with Wordpress on Linode.

Comment: Yay, got it all working with that guide! Just put up my first page on the VPS using mysql_connect to prove it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed MySQL from source you would also have to install/compile `mysql-connector` so that PHP can find the required header files.